# Возможна ли интеллектуальная поддержка в vim для python3?

Tags: python-3.6, vim

Существует ли плагин vim для python3, осуществляющий интеллектуальную поддержку, т.е высвечивающий имена функций переменных и тд? Или в терминале такое в принципе не возможно?

Comment: подстветка синтаксиса — это же [базовая функциональность программы vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html). прямо из коробки есть подсветка для десятков языков. и python в том числе.

Comment: Если под "высвечиванием" понимается автодополнение, то могу порекомендовать YouCompleteMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему же, есть плагин [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim), который добавляет автокомплит и загрузку информации из doc'стрингов как библиотек, так и пользовательского кода.
Если вам нужна только подсветка, то можно воспользоваться плагином  [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot), он добавляет поддержку и разные другие фичи для большого количества языков в вим